# parsing data to listview in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

### I am trying to display parsed jason data to listview

**ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView name;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_for_atomic_list_item_type, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_id_atomic_list_item_type);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        name.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));


        return itemView;
    }
}
```

**BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.java**

```
public class BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse extends Activity{
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "rank";


    String TYPE_FILTER;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        TYPE_FILTER = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_title");


        Log.v("---- Value-MC---", TYPE_FILTER);
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            String newurl = "?" + "Key=" + TYPE_FILTER.trim();


            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7005/RestaurantAtomicListItemType/"+newurl);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put(MainActivity.NAME, jsonobject.getString("MasterListMenuName"));

                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapterForAtomicListItemtype(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**::

```
12-30 14:34:25.056: V/---- Value-MC---(1266): Main Course
12-30 14:34:27.196: E/log_tag(1266): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 64: http://54.218.73.244:7005/RestaurantAtomicListItemType/?Key=Main Course
12-30 14:34:27.196: E/log_tag(1266): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 14:34:27.214: E/log_tag(1266): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-30 14:34:27.224: W/dalvikvm(1266): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at com.project.findmybuffet.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.java:79)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at com.project.findmybuffet.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse$DownloadJSON.doInBackground(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.java:1)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-30 14:34:27.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1266):     ... 4 more
12-30 14:34:27.384: D/dalvikvm(1266): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2532 objects / 166712 bytes in 93ms
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266): Activity com.project.findmybuffet.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f511f8 that was originally added here
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.project.findmybuffet.BreakfastLunchDinnerIndividualListOfItems has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f511f8 that was originally added here
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at com.project.findmybuffet.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse$DownloadJSON.onPreExecute(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.java:63)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at com.project.findmybuffet.BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.onCreate(BLD_IndividualListOfItems_MainCourse.java:46)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-30 14:34:28.654: E/WindowManager(1266):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: just print the "jsonobject" response to check whether it get a correct response or not

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 64: .............how can i resolve this its happening because i have a space between "Main Course".... but postman did yield result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use %20 for space in your main course like below

```
  http://54.218.73.244:7005/RestaurantAtomicListItemType/?Key=Main%20Course
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what i was looking for ... http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm .... for other encodings .... if anyone looking for similar scenario